# MOSFET push-pull low current problem

Tags: mosfet, push-pull

I am trying to make a push-pull amp to drive a dc motor with a dual power supply.
I have this circuit and it works but I can only get about 1A of current for each rail.
Is it possible to raise this current? I have tried several configurations in falstad simulator
but I haven't found a way to do it, except when swapping sources to drains but then I think the circuit is a short circuit between the rails.

Thanks

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCu4Nn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]
[image]

EDIT:
I have swapped the diodes with resistors and tried several values but I don't see any difference. The current climbs to +- 0.85A.

Comment: Check the way your supply voltages are drawn. The first schematic either has V2 the wrong way around or it should be 12V not -12V, in the others the bottom battery symbol should be the other way around and should be defined as a positive voltage, otherwise it's confusing since the side with the longer line is usually positive and there are no labels on them to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I thought to flip the negative PS vertically but I think this is the correct way to depict it. Ground is + in the negative rail. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If you make a voltage source negative it reverses the marked polarity, the - will be positive and the + will be negative. If you need a negative supply you either make it a positive voltage and make the + common, or make it a negative voltage and make the - common. You've made it a negative voltage with the + common so if this was in a simulator it wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: ok. I ll check it out

Answer (score 2):

The diodes are preventing proper gate bias. Replace them with resistors (\$R_{3},R_{4}\$) so that the voltage drop across each resistor just under \$V_{T}\$. Also a resistor from the junction of the FET source to the junction of \$R_{3},R_{4}\$ may help with smooth startup from zero.

The circuit will dissipate a lot of power. You will need big heatsinks on the transistors. A pulse width modulation (pwm) driver is better.

EDIT: the current draw depends entirely on the motor. The voltage applied to the motor is:
$$V_{motor}=12V-V_{GS}~=8V$$
If the motor resistance is about \$10\Omega \$, then the current will be \$0.8 A\$. The circuit is operating properly. The reason for replacing the diodes with resistors is to remove the dead band near zero.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit.

Comment: Looks like the circuit is behaving correctly in both cases. The most voltage that you can apply to the motor is about 8 volts.

Comment: See my edit. You can't just get more current. The current is determined by the motor voltage and the motor resistance.

Comment: If I use the mosfets seperately I can make them provide 2-3 amps. I think it is the push pull configuration that limits the current.

Comment: MOSFETS don't provide current. The voltage to the motor must be increased. The motor draws current based on its resistance.

Comment: with provide i meant allow current to pass from the ps to the load. if i use a mosfet alone i can make it to "provide" 2-3 amps. i.e. the motor can consume 2-3 amps. I have here a small dc motor and a larger one. The circuit can drive the small motor but not the bigger one.

Comment: @JohnAm: Please post the motors' specifications

Comment: I can't really read the specs. The small is a common cheap "disk drive" motor. The biggest is inside a printer I hack. It doesn't matter the motor. Let's say I use a coil. If I use a single mosfet like 9520 or 520, I can make it consume 2 amps. But with the configuration I posted that allows me to use a dual supply the current is limited to 500mA per rail. Anyway I don't want to bother you. It is probably something I miss or something that confuses me. I will have to spend some more time with this. Thank you Mr.